# Give X3DOM access to <x3d> elements inside Polymer.Element

Tags: dom, polymer, public, x3dom

I want to use x3dom together with my PolymerElements, but if I put the needed x3d tag inside my Polymer.Element, X3Dom states, that no containers are found, because it uses `document.getElementsByTagName('X3D');`

see here: https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/blob/652f3d4acd5e9e9f62b3ecdd92dec5e5c8a2fd86/src/Main.js#L25

Is there a way to make dom elements 'public' so that they can be found by libraries like x3dom?

P.S.: A working solution I found is by 'slotting' the element through to the actual destination.

Example:

```
<body>
    <my-custom-element>
        <x3d ...> ... </x3d>
    </my-customelement>
    <script src="x3dom-full.js">
</body>
```

Works, if I design my Element like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-custom-element">
    <template>
        <style></style>
        <slot></slot>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

In case I design my element like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-custom-element">
    <template>
        <style></style>
        <x3d></x3d>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

x3dom cannot find it, even if the script tag for x3dom-full.js lies inside the template tag.

The reason I do not prefer the slot tags is that I want to hide the x3dom functionality inside my custom element.